# What is wrong with my code to remove duplicates from Linked List?

Tags: python

New to Python and my code is passing all test cases other than input 1-->0, which it returns nothing instead of 1->0. does this have something to do with the value of None?

```
def RemoveDuplicates(head):
    if head == None or head.next == None:
        return 
    else:
        temp = head
        while(temp.next != None):
            if temp.data == temp.next.data:
                temp.next = temp.next.next
            else:
                temp = temp.next
        return head
```

Comment: "what is wrong with my code...?" First of all — broken indentation

Comment: My guess is that you should `return head` in the first conditional instead of just `return`, which is equivalent to returning `None`.

Comment: Also, side-note: Never test `== None` or `!= None`. `None` is a singleton, and invoking the full rich comparison machinery for it is wasteful. Test `is None` or `is not None` instead, which is an identity test, effectively, a pointer comparison at the C layer, instead of a complicated set of calls to some combination of (depending on Python version) `__coerce__`, `__cmp__`, `__eq__` and/or `__ne__`.

Comment: Could you please give more details on the expected behaviour? This looks like it will only detect successive duplicates, but if the duplicated values are not directly sequential then they will not be detected. Is this intended? e.g 3->3 contains duplicated 3s, but 3->4->3 does not?

Comment: Could you share the executable code with sample data

Answer (score 0):

Try `is None` instead of `== None`.  Comparisons to singletons should be done using `is` or `is not`.

Comment: This is good advice, but it almost certainly has nothing to do with the problem, it's mostly just a performance and style fix (the times when it would affect correctness are few and far between). It doesn't actually resolve or even address the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can't see the class of head and what operations it has defined, is the `__eq__` magic function defined on that class?

Is it possible that `head.next == None` evaluates to `head.next.data == None` for the class?  In which case `0 == None` evaluates to True.

As others have mentioned this is fixed by using `head.next is None`

I suspect you're supposed to `return head` in the first case regardless, but it doesn't seem like it should be triggering in this case unless the evaluations I mention above are happening.